# Why scheduled cron jobs are not executed?

Tags: linux, cron

I am working on a embedded-linux device with a custom Linux distribution and I have a cron job configured via `crontab` and it executes a script every 10 mins. The script is executable and the cron job was working fine. But, now all of a sudden it has stopped working and I don' see any reason why the scheduled job is not being executed. The `crontab -e` contains:

```
*/10 * * * * /bin/bash /home/user/tmp/test.sh >> /home/user/tmp/test_log.txt 2>&1
```

This was working fine and now this job is not executed at all. The script `test.sh` is not modified and is a simple bash scrit which calls an application in `/usr/bin/`. The crontab file also ends with a newline. And no `PATH` is set in `/etc/environment` file.

In order to check the environment variables passed by the cron to the jobs, I added below entry to crontab:

```
* * * * * env > /tmp/env.output
```

After comparing output from `env.output` and `env` (from terminal), the `PATH` attribute conatins:

from `env.output`

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
```

from `env` (from terminal)

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin
```

Can anyone please let me know why the jobs are not executed by cron?

Thanks in advance.

P.S: please let me know if any info is missing

Comment: You are logging everything to a `test_log.txt` file. Does that file hold any clues to what's happening?

Comment: @Kusalananda, the log fie contains only the logs when the job is executed. No errors are logged when the job is not executed.

Comment: Do you have access to the logs from the cron daemon? I don't know where these would be stored on your custom embedded Linux system...

Comment: try restarting the cron-service, just to be sure...

Comment: I would start by putting debug code into `/home/user/tmp/test.sh`.

Comment: @Bib, could you please let me know what do you mean by putting debug code into `/home/user/tmp/test.sh`?

Comment: @markgraf, yes I tried this and no luck. Sometime it's executing but it's weird and not consistent. Should I restart the crontab after power-up or reboot? I assume if the cron daemon is running then no need to start crontab explicitly.

Comment: No, that shouldn't be necessary. Weird.

Comment: How about adding a line in the script that says `echo "Im here" >> /tmp/debug.txt`. Then put more in as seen fit.